# Going back to Start Screen leads into stacking the views in each other

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui

Everytime I am going back to the start screen it seems that it stacks itself. You can see what i mean in the screenshot i attached. I added some borders so you can see what i mean [image]

The code of the Start screen:

```
struct StartScreen: View {

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            
            VStack() {
                
                Image("Headline").resizable().scaledToFit()
                Image("GreenMonster")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(alignment: .top)
 
                NavigationLink(destination: Game(monster: monster)) {
                    Text("Spielen")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                    )
                    
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                
                /*
                 NavigationLink(destination: Settings()){
                 Image("Settingswheel").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 50, height: 50).offset(x: 150)
                 }
                 
                 */
                
            }
            
            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).border(Color.green)
            
    }
}
```

and the code to go back is:

```
struct DefeatedView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var helper: Helper
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView(){
            VStack(){
                Text("BESIEGT!").foregroundColor(.green).font(.title).bold()
                Image(monster[0].imageURL).resizable().scaledToFit()
                NavigationLink(destination: StartScreen()){
                    Text("Zum Start").frame(width: 120, height: 6, alignment: .center)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                    )
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help i am new into SwiftUI

Comment: i forgot to mention i have a game that is running between those two views. if you need the code of that game i can put it in as well.

Comment: This `NavigationLink(destination: StartScreen())` is not go back to StartScreen, it is go forward creating new StartScreen on top of existing StartScreen>DetailView, so you just cycle creation again and again. Rethink design.

Comment: As Asperi says, the logic is wrong. Read about @Environment presentationMode, to push it back manually to your Start view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `DefeatedView`

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

And then instead of using a `NavigationLink` again, use a button and push your View manually back to your Start View

```
Button(action: {
    //Push navigation view back
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
})
{
    Text("Zum Start").frame(width: 120, height: 6, alignment: .center)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(40)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(10)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
    )
}
```

**Edit:**

As you pushed your `NavigationView` twice, calling presentation mode only once will indeed push back to your Game View. Here is a possible solution with `ObservableObject`.

```
class ViewHelper : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var finishedGame : Bool = false
}

struct StartScreen: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewHelper : ViewHelper

    var body: some View {
    
    NavigationLink(destination: Game(), isActive: self.$viewHelper.finishedGame) {
        Text("Spielen")
```

And then when the gameplay Is finished, change the `finishedGame` variable.

```
struct DefeatedView: View {
        
    @EnvironmentObject var viewHelper : ViewHelper

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView(){
            VStack(){
                Text("BESIEGT!").foregroundColor(.green).font(.title).bold()
                Button(action: {
                    self.viewHelper.finishedGame = false
                })
                {
                    Text("Zum Start").frame(width: 120, height: 6, alignment: .center)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                    )
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

Comment: i used your code technically it worked but the problem is that i am going back to my game not to the start screen

Comment: @DominicPfeifer You are correct. I have updated the code which works using ObservableObject and isActive parameter on NavigationLink :)

Comment: Thank you i found a similiar solution like yours !

Comment: No problem. Grüße nach Frankfurt :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my Problem on this Site:

https://thinkdiff.net/ios/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view/